# what are the technologies I have worked on for this Bike Configuration

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, animation

what are the technologies I have worked on for this Bike Configuration

https://dribbble.com/shots/7120561-Bike-Configuration

Comment: Wouldn't you know that?

Comment: It's only link on a video. Any reference on demo? It looks like simple animation, not web, video production.

Comment: I want to build that type of a web app. can I do it using HTML, CSS and js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using vanilla HTML, CSS and JS.